# Eliminar registos repetidos em PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, query

Bom dia, estou aqui com uma dúvida bastante grande.
Ando nisto há um dia inteiro e ainda não consegui resolver a situação.
Tenho uma base de dados em sql server e preciso de apresentar uns botões com os registos da descrição de uma tabela, mas passe-se que nesse tabela existem registos que podem ser repetidos, neste caso tenho restaurante 4 vezes devido ao restaurante ter mais que uma mesa.
Vou mostrar-vos o print do resultado e deixar aqui o código caso me possam ajudar.[image: Resultado do meu código]

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<?php

  $sql="SELECT P.id as Id, 
     P.pointOfSale as [Description], 
     P.printerExtrat1 as PrinterExtrat1, 
     P.printerExtrat1FonteTicket as PrinterExtrat1Font, 
     P.printerExtrat2 as PrinterExtrat2, 
     P.printerExtrat2FonteTicket as PrinterExtrat2Font, 
     P.printerExtrat3 as PrinterExtrat3, 
     P.printerExtrat3FonteTicket as PrinterExtrat3Font, 
     T.id as IdTable, 
     T.tableDescription as TableDescription 
     FROM PointOfSale P LEFT 
     JOIN PointOfSalesTables T ON P.id=T.idPointOfSale and T.isActive=1 
     WHERE P.isActive=1 
     ORDER BY P.pointOfSale";
  $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
  
 while ($row1 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $result, SQLSRV_FETCH_NUMERIC)) {
  $resultado1 = $row1[1];
  ?>
  
  <body>
   <form method="post">
    <a  class="banquetes"><?php echo $resultado1; ?></a>
   </form>
  </body>
  <?php
  }
?>
```

Não posso mostrar mais código devido a ser confidencial as ligações à base de dados.

Answer (score 5):

Uma possibilidade é acrescentar esta linha em sua *query*:

```sql
GROUP BY P.id
```

Atenção à posição, em SQL as cláusulas tem ordem específica:

```sql
...
WHERE P.isActive=1 
GROUP BY P.id               -- ou T.idPointOfSale, claro
ORDER BY P.pointOfSale";
```

O `GROUP BY` faz com que os resultados sejam (como o nome já diz) agrupados em uma linha só para cada ocorrência do campo selecionado (no caso, um ID único de cada ponto de venda)

Ajuste o campo acima se necessário. Eu não sugeri usar o nome, pois você poderia ter 2 "restaurante" se tratando de coisas diferentes, então preferi o `ID`. Pode ser que no seu caso o nome seja mais adequado. O importante é entender o funcionamento.

Note que não se aplica ao seu caso, mas o `GROUP BY` serve para mais do que limitar a saída. Ele é muito importante para que você possa contar, somar, determinar o maior ou menor registro em sua *query*.

Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT tipo, COUNT(*), SUM( valor ) FROM tabela GROUP BY tipo
```

Isto faria com que apenas fosse mostrado uma linha de cada `tipo`, em seguida a contagem de quantas linhas de cada `tipo`, e a soma dos valores somente daquele `tipo`.

Alternativamente poderia estudar o uso do `DISTINCT`, mas só sabendo mais detalhes da sua implementaçao e objetivo (se bem que, internamente, em muitos DBs o `DISTINCT`.é implementado como um caso específico de `GROUP BY`, muitas vezes resultando no mesmo plano de execução):

```sql
 SELECT  DISTINCT P.id     AS Id, 
         P.pointOfSale     AS [Description], 
         P.printerExtrat1  AS PrinterExtrat1,
```

Comment: Acrescentei mas fica a dar erro na linha sqlsrv_fetch_array(), que diz expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: Este erro é sinal de que o GROUP provavelmente foi posto na posição errada (a ordem de cada cláusula do SQL é específica), ou algum erro de digitação, e a query falhou. Importante não só neste caso, como em geral, imprimir o erro do SQL durante o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta ilustrando melhor

Answer (score 0):

É possivel resolver isso de 2 maneiras, pelo query ou pelo php,

Com o query podes fazer um group by dessa coluna, portanto nao te vai dar dados repetidos.

Em php podes fazer algo do genero (nao aconselho)

```
 $resultado1 = $row1[1];
 if($lastWord == $resultado1){
 //MOSTRAR HTML
 }else{
  //Ñ MOSTRAR HTML
 }
 $lastWord = $resultado1
```

Comment: Pelo php não resultou mas vou então tentar o group by

Comment: eu enganei me, tens de trocar o if eu pus ao contrario, se forem iguais nao mostra

Comment: Não deixa de ser uma opção, mas seu IF não funcionaria, seria mais fácil ter um array com as chaves repetidas e usar `array_unique` para eliminar a duplicidade. O porém fica se for um sistema de paginação, onde se espera N itens para completar uma lista e remove-se as duplicatas...

Answer (score -1):

Melissa,
Pelo que eu entendi do script (não consegui abrir a imagem devido restrições de firewall) as tentativas de group by e/ou dictinct não vão funcionar, pois no retorno você terá algo como:

```
Id - Description - .... - IdTable ...
1  - Restaurante1 - .... - 1
2  - Restaurante1 - .... - 3
```

Acredito que terá diferenças nas colunas Id, IdTable, TableDescription ...
Sugiro que retire as colunas que não vá usar na consulta pois com $row1[1] você só mostra a [Description].
E adicione o Distinct como já mencionado.